# Does TPS metric include failed transactions in the calculation?

Tags: transactions, slots, failed, tps

I'm new to Solana and I was reading about TPS metric. I got there are vote and non-vote transactions in it, but what about failed transactions? Let's say we have this slot:

[image: slot 155257417]

and the transaction success rate is 59%. Failed transactions are included in slots of course, but this means that 59% of 4230 transaction, so about 2495, are actually successful or 4230 already represents the number of successful transactions as is? So are failed transactions included in the TPS calculation or not?